# Haskell Print while in recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion

```
foo:: Int -> Int -> Int
foo z x = if (z < 100) 
             then z * foo (z+(x*z)) z
             else z
```

How would you print out(the integer z) an output every time it gets called from itself?Can you have function that returns an IO and Int? Do you need a secondary function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For simplicity, you can use [trace](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace). However it's not welcomed for real production code as it breaks referential transparency.
`trace` takes a `String` to print and a value to return.

```
import Debug.Trace

foo:: Int -> Int -> Int
foo z x = trace ("z = " ++ show z) $ if (z < 100) 
    then z * foo (z+(x*z)) z
    else z

*Main> foo 1 2
 z = 1
 z = 3
 z = 6
 z = 24
 z = 168
 72576
```

Answer (score 11):

For completeness, I'm going to answer this question:

> Can you have function that returns an IO and Int?

...quite literally. The answer is "yes!"... and it's even sometimes useful. Likely this isn't what you want to do as a beginner, but in case it is, here's a sample.

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> (IO (), Int)
foo z x = if z < 100 then (print z >> io, z * rec) else (return (), z) where
    (io, rec) = foo (z+x*z) z
```

For example, you could print the recursive calls by setting

```
main = fst $ foo 13 7
```

or you could just print the answer by setting

```
main = print . snd $ foo 13 7
```

or half a dozen other things. Of course, the `IO ()` type is a bit hard to inspect; you might consider writing something like this instead:

```
foo' :: Int -> Int -> Writer [Int] Int
foo' z x = if z < 100
    then tell [z] >> fmap (z*) (foo' (z+x*z) z)
    else return z
```

Using this is pretty similar to the above, but with an extra `runWriter` thrown in; for example, you could write either of these two:

```
main = print . snd . runWriter $ foo' 13 7 -- to print a list of the calling values
main = print . fst . runWriter $ foo' 13 7 -- to print the result
```

The advantage of this method is that you get back a list of calling values, rather than an IO action that prints that list, so you can munge the calls in many more interesting ways.

Comment: +1 our Haskell newbies should be introduced to things like `Writer` much sooner than we typically teach them.

Comment: @DanBurton, if we introduce X sooner, we must introduce Y later.  What is Y in this case?

Comment: @luqui imho list comprehensions are taught too soon. It is true that they are fairly straightforward to understand, but it is better for the student to learn the actual monad interface and then later learn how comprehension syntax desugars to it. I daresay that writing your own typeclasses and your own instances should come later as well, though I haven't given much thought to the ramifications of that.

Comment: @luqui : I guess Debug.Trace.trace then

Comment: Could you comment on the performance implications of using `Writer` with a list instead of a `DList`?

Answer (score 6):

Building on @is7s's answer, a useful idiom for using `Debug.Trace` is to do this:

```
import Debug.Trace

foo:: Int -> Int -> Int
foo z x | trace ("z = " ++ show z) False = undefined
foo z x = if (z < 100) 
    then z * foo (z+(x*z)) z
    else z
```

Here, we have introduced a definition of `foo` with the `trace` in a guard which evaluates to `False`, so that it will always fall-through to the original definition.  In this way, we do not perturb our function, and can turn the tracing on or off by commenting out the line.

Answer (score 4):

Any function that performs I/O must return its result in the `IO` monad:

```
 foo :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
 foo z x = print z >> if z < 100 then fmap (z*) (foo (z + x * z) z) else return z
```

Notice that both branches of the `if` expression must now be in `IO` as well.

This is not the same as returning "an `IO` and `Int`". `IO Int` is the type of a value that represents an I/O action which, when executed, will produce an `Int` as its result (possibly after doing some I/O). So the above definition of `foo` takes an `Int` and an `Int` and returns an I/O action that will eventually result in an `Int`.